# How to overlay graphs using includegraphics or pstricks?

Tags: pstricks, postscript

I have a figure (eps file included using `\includegraphics`) inside a `postscript` environment where I use PSTricks to add labels and extra lines.

I want to add another eps file smaller in the top right so it is on the top of the other figure.
Can I use `\includegraphics` or something similar (possibly in PSTricks) to put a new eps file partially on top of the other one, in the same `postscript` environment?

I want the result to look a bit like this:
[image: Graph with a second graph overlayed in the corner.]

Comment: To add some background, I generally run my eps files through processing with psfrag / pstricks and anything else to produce a pdf file which can then be directly dropped into a document compiled with pdflatex (and not using any --shell-escape).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\Row{5}
\def\Column{5}
\def\FilenameMain{example-image-A}
\def\FilenameChild{example-image-B}
\def\ScaleMain{1}
\def\ScaleChild{0.25}


\newsavebox\IBoxMain
\newsavebox\IBoxChild
\savebox\IBoxMain{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleMain]{\FilenameMain}}
\savebox\IBoxChild{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleChild]{\FilenameChild}}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBoxMain/\Column,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBoxMain/\Row,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\Column,\Row)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBoxMain}
    \rput[tr](4.5,4.5){\usebox\IBoxChild}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit:

You might need a grid to exactly specify the position of the child figure. Then the following edit should help. Of course you have to turn off the grid at the final stage by changing `showgrid=top` to `showgrid=false`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\Row{5}
\def\Column{5}
\def\FilenameMain{example-image-A}
\def\FilenameChild{example-image-B}
\def\ScaleMain{1}
\def\ScaleChild{0.25}


\newsavebox\IBoxMain
\newsavebox\IBoxChild
\savebox\IBoxMain{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleMain]{\FilenameMain}}
\savebox\IBoxChild{\includegraphics[scale=\ScaleChild]{\FilenameChild}}

\psset
{
    xunit=\dimexpr\wd\IBoxMain/\Column,
    yunit=\dimexpr\ht\IBoxMain/\Row,
}

\addtopsstyle{gridstyle}
{
    griddots=0,
    gridcolor=red,
    subgridcolor=white,
    subgriddiv=10,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=top](\Column,\Row)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBoxMain}
    \rput[tr](4.5,4.5){\usebox\IBoxChild}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit 2:

Compile the code above with either `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` sequence or a single call `xelatex` to obtain a PDF output (namely `overlaid.pdf`).

Later, from your main TeX input file, you can then import the PDF output (`overlaid.pdf`) as follows.

```
% this is the main TeX input file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[<any options>]{overlaid}
\caption{Overlaid image in action}
\label{fig:overlaid}
\end{figure}
Your text goes here...
\end{document}
```

Compile this main TeX input file with `pdflatex`. Note that this workflow makes your project well organized and cleaner.

Comment: This answer is very helpful. I hadn't seen the standalone documentclass before. It also seems to be a very configurable version for what I want to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `picture` environment; with the help of the `picture` and `calc` packages we can easily place both graphs, the important thing is that the inner one is typeset after the outer one. Notice that this does not depend on `pstricks`, so it is a more portable solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,picture,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
%% Use two temporary storage bins
\sbox0{\includegraphics{Graph1}}
\sbox2{\includegraphics{Graph2}} % add the necessary scaling options

\begin{picture}(\wd0,\ht0)
\put(0,0){\usebox0}
%% Adjust the -0.7cm and -0.5cm shifts
\put(\wd0 - \wd2 - 0.7cm,\ht0 - \ht2 - 0.5cm){\usebox{2}}
\end{picture}
\caption{Two graphs}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\SpecialCoor
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,3)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame, ticksize=0 5pt](6,3)
\rput[tr](!6 0.25 sub 3 0.25 sub){\fbox{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{tiger}}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as Garbage Collector's answer (using `\rput` inside a `pspicture`)?

Comment: I don't understand how the coordinates work here. Also, I don't want to live-draw the large graph, I already have the eps file that I want to include.

Comment: @Dom: The PostScript notation in `(!6 0.25 sub 3 0.25 sub)` equals to `(5.75,2.75)`.

Comment: Ok, I get it, the ! means do a calculation, and the sub means subtraction. Thanks.

Comment: @Dom `!` means that the following code is pure PostScript. There are other possibilities, too

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I am including here my final result as a minimal working example.

It is based on [Garbage Collector's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97878/672) but heavily simplified.
There are many extra parts, which are very useful to know but this is a simpler initial step.

It uses the `\rput` command inside the postscript environment.
This example can also be compiled directly with pdflatex (because it uses `auto-pst-pdf`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{postscript}
\includegraphics[width=324pt]{parent-filename}
\rput(-3.7,5.3){\includegraphics[width=180pt]{child-filename}}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

This simply adds the child figure on top of the already positioned parent figure.
The coordinates for rput are strange, because the initial `\includegraphics` is not inside an rput and somehow sets the `0,0` as bottom right.