# shapes inside the figure

Tags: graphics

I am inserting an .eps figure. So is it possible to include some geometric shapes (ellipse, rectangle) inside the inserted eps figure. I googled, but couldn't find a proper solution. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Do you want to edit the eps and add some shapes (clearly postscript can draw shapes) or do you want to include an unchanged eps and overlay some latex drawn shapes using tikz or picture environment or pstricks etc, any of these are possible

Comment: So you want to add a moustache to Mona Lisa? Seriously, could you give some more details about what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for your response. I will put the question in other way. For. Eg. If there is an image of human face (.eps) inserted into the latex. I would like to make a square over two eyes and an ellipse over the mouth.

Comment: @Bernard I think you should answer with your original comment suggestion:-)

Comment: @David  Carlisle: Done…

Comment: @Bernard hmm thought you were going to use a tikz overlay?

Comment: @bernard.. FInally I think, i didn't get the answer to my question.

Comment: @user8162: It was just a joke, not knowing what to propose without any further details (I hadn't read your comment  yet). I'm truly sorry if I hurt you.

Comment: @Bernard, I will put the question in other way. For. Eg. If there is an image of human face (.eps) inserted into the latex. I would like to make a square over two eyes and an ellipse over the mouth. If this is still not clear, I can give some more examples, if you want..

Comment: Since it is an .eps image I would do that with `pstricks` by trial and erors. Maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97877/how-to-overlay-graphs-using-includegraphics-or-pstricks) might help.

Comment: See any of the following (possible duplicates; despite the fact that the image is EPS): [Simplest way to overlay a text + rectangle label an image?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30427/5764); [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764)

Answer (score 4):

You can use any latex drawing package to draw over an image, `tikz`, `pstricks` or here I just use the standard latex `picture` commands, enhanced via the `pict2e` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\begin{document}

Original:

\includegraphics{man}


enhanced

\includegraphics{man}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-80,150){\framebox(10,10){}}
\put(-60,150){\framebox(10,10){}}
\put(-70,140){\oval(20,5){}}
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```